# Trying to implement stripe's applepay in an embeddable widget

Tags: stripe-payments, postmessage, applepay, applepay-web

I'm creating a website that users can embed into their various websites through an iframe. I'm trying to integrate stripe applepay on my own website so the users embedding it in their websites can have access to it.  But on trying payment with applepay through the iframe,
I get the error below.
Note: the website the iframe is hosted on is registered for stripe apple pay.

How do i go about fixing this?

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Could not create Apple Pay session. Please make sure you have registered this Stripe account. For more information, see https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#web.",
    "request_log_url": "https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_grewzWQGjfn97s?t=1706806957",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what Stripe component you use, but most of them requires to [register your domain with Apple via Stripe Dashboard](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration?platform=dashboard#register-your-domain).

Comment: I'm using Elements from stripe and I have my domain registered.